# redirect to index instead of show after create or save data

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, json, view

I want to go to the index view directly after entering (create/new/update) the data. Right now after entering the data the show view is displayed. I tried to change render: show into render: index, but this did not work.

This is my controller:

```
class ElectricityGenerationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user
  before_action :set_electricity_generation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]`

  # GET /electricity_generations
  # GET /electricity_generations.json
  def index
    @scenario_selection = Selection.find_by_resource("scenario").name
    @selected_scenarios = Selection.find_by_resource("scenario").scenario_id
    @electricity_generations = ElectricityGeneration.where(scenario_id: @selected_scenarios)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html #index.html.erb
      format.json {render json: @electricity_generations}
    end
  end

  # GET /electricity_generations/1
  # GET /electricity_generations/1.json
  def show
    @scenario_selections = Selection.find_by_resource("scenario").name
    @electricity_generation = ElectricityGeneration.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html #show.html.erb
      format.json {render json: @electricity_generations}
    end
  end

  # GET /electricity_generations/new
  def new
    @scenario_selections = Selection.find_by_resource("scenario").name
    @electricity_generation = ElectricityGeneration.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html #new.html.erb
      format.json {render json: @electricity_generations}
    end
  end

  # GET /electricity_generations/1/edit
  def edit
    @scenario_selections = Selection.find_by_resource("scenario").name
    @electricity_generation = ElectricityGeneration.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /electricity_generations
  # POST /electricity_generations.json
  def create
    @selected_scenarios = Selection.find_by_resource("scenario").scenario_id
    @electricity_generation = ElectricityGeneration.new(electricity_generation_params)
    @electricity_generation.id = ElectricityGeneration.last.id + 1
    @electricity_generation.scenario_id = Selection.find_by_resource("scenario").scenario_id
    @scenario_selections = Selection.find_by_resource("scenario").name
    @electricity_generation.user_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @electricity_generation.save
        format.html { redirect_to @electricity_generation, notice: 'Electricity Generation Information was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @electricity_generation }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @electricity_generation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /electricity_generations/1
  # PATCH/PUT /electricity_generations/1.json
  def update
    @scenario_selections = Selection.find_by_resource("scenario").name
    @electricity_generation.user_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @electricity_generation.update(electricity_generation_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @electricity_generation, notice: 'Electricity Generation was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @electricity_generation }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @electricity_generation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /electricity_generations/1
  # DELETE /electricity_generations/1.json
  def destroy
    @scenario_selections = Selection.find_by_resource("scenario").name
    @electricity_generation.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to electricity_generations_url, notice: 'Electricity generation was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end


  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_electricity_generation
      @electricity_generation = ElectricityGeneration.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def electricity_generation_params
      params.require(:electricity_generation).permit(:user_id, :annual_solar_irradiation, :asi_max, :asi_min, :scenario_id)
    end
end
```

Comment: It seems like you used scaffolds, which always make a mess.  If you want to go back to the index you use redirect_to electricity_generators_path

Comment: Yes, i used scaffolds. should i replace the "render  :show" with "redirect_to electricity_generators_path"?

Comment: You should yes...though I avoid using scaffolds myself as the extraneous code can get in the way.

Comment: Thanks, I changed `format.html { redirect_to @electricity_generation, notice: 'Electricity Generation was successfully updated.' }` into `format.html { redirect_to @electricity_generations_path, notice: 'Electricity Generation was successfully updated.' } `and the `format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @electricity_generation }` remains the same. It Works!

Comment: That won't work either though...your paths are not instance variables.  redirect_to electricity_generations_path.  If you're unsure about path names, in your app root folder type rake routes and it will show you all available paths and what they need to work.

Comment: Sorry, this was a typo, of course i left the @ in the changed code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only redirects to the root path, like so;

```
    format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'My Notice.' }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `redirect_to %url_helper_to_your_index%` instead of `render :show`.